# meaning of "mind-twisting"

Tags: meaning, robert-jordan, wheel-of-time

> The palace still shook occasionally as the earth rumbled in memory,
> groaned as if it would deny what had happened. Bars of sunlight cast
> through rents in the walls made motes of dust glitter where they yet
> hung in the air. Scorch-marks marred the walls, the floors, the
> ceilings. Broad black smears crossed the blistered paints and gilt of
> once-bright murals, soot overlaying crumbling friezes of men and
> animals which seemed to have attempted to walk before the madness grew
> quiet. The dead lay everywhere, men and women and children, struck
> down in attempted flight by the lightnings that had flashed down every
> corridor, or seized by the fires that had stalked them, or sunken into
> stone of the palace, the stones that had flowed and sought, almost
> alive, before stillness came again. In odd counterpoint, colorful
> tapestries and paintings, masterworks all, hung undisturbed except
> where bulging walls had pushed them awry. Finely carved furnishings,
> inlaid with ivory and gold, stood untouched except where rippling
> floors had toppled them. The **mind-twisting** had struck at the core,
> ignoring peripheral things.

This the first paragraph of [The Eye of the World](https://www.torforgeblog.com/2020/05/04/read-part-1-the-eye-of-the-world/), Robert Jordan's first book of The Wheel of Time series. What does "mind-twisting" mean?

Answer (score 1):

In this context Mr Jordan is referring to an in-universe concept *called* "Mind-Twisting", which is essentially what it says on the tin - physically twisting things using one's mind.